# Scoring an American Football Game?

Tags: american-football, statistics, scoring

Is there an analog to baseball's scorecard for football?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_scorekeeping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not really possible to keep score in football like you do in baseball (in baseball you capture a lot of data that would be impossible to capture in football), they do make scorebooks for football games so that you can track various statistics (like you'd track hits, homeruns, strikeouts etc in baseball).

Here is an example a quick search on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GFWC64) turns up. This obviously doesn't have a very good look at what the pages look like, but it appears it has space to track plays through the game (possibly even indicating formation, yardage and how the runner/receiver ran his route).

It should be noted that similar score tracking devices are employed in football (soccer), and basketball. They don't have the same nostalgia factor you see in baseball scorekeeping (I've never seen a picture of a fan in a stadium for any of football, american football or basketball keeping score, whereas its common practice in baseball to distribute score sheets in programs).